# Where exactly is the error in the CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am faced with the fact that my CloudFormation template is greater than 51200 bytes. So I decided to split this main template into several templates. When I try to build the stack, I get an error that the resource properties in the nested template are not correct.

**QUESTION**:

Is it possible that the nested template doesn't see the parameter values that were declared in the main template?

**Error**:

```
Invalid template resource property 'CreateWidgetRole'
```

**template.yaml** (snippet):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
  SettingsServiceStackName:
    Type: String
  S3Bucket:
    Type: String
Conditions:
  IsProductionEnvironment:
    'Fn::Equals':
      - Ref: EnvironmentName
      - Prod
Resources:
  SettingsServiceResources:
    'Fn::Transform':
      Name: 'AWS::Include'
      Parameters:
        Location:
          'Fn::Sub': >-
            s3://${S3Bucket}/included_templates/settings_service_resources_template.yaml
```

**settings_service_resources_template.yam**l:

```
CreateWidgetRole:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: appsync.amazonaws.com
          Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: CreateWidgetFunctionAccess
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
              Resource:
                'Fn::ImportValue':
                  'Fn::Sub': >-
                    ${EnvironmentName}${SettingsServiceStackName}:${EnvironmentName}CreateWidgetARN
CreateWidgetDataSource:
  Type: 'AWS::AppSync::DataSource'
  Properties:
    ApiId:
      'Fn::GetAtt': GraphQLApi.ApiId
    Name:
      'Fn::Sub': '${EnvironmentName}CreateWidget'
    Type: AWS_LAMBDA
    LambdaConfig:
      LambdaFunctionArn:
        'Fn::ImportValue':
          'Fn::Sub': >-
            ${EnvironmentName}${SettingsServiceStackName}:${EnvironmentName}CreateWidgetARN
    ServiceRoleArn:
      'Fn::GetAtt': CreateWidgetRole.Arn
CreateWidgetResolver:
  Type: 'AWS::AppSync::Resolver'
  Properties:
    ApiId:
      'Fn::GetAtt': GraphQLApi.ApiId
    FieldName: createWidget
    TypeName: Mutation
    DataSourceName:
      'Fn::GetAtt': CreateWidgetDataSource.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `SettingsServiceResources` line in the `template.yaml`. All your resources in the nested template have Logical IDs (like `CreateWidgetRole`), so there is no need to put another one in front of the Transform block. The following worked for me:

```
Resources:
  'Fn::Transform':
    Name: 'AWS::Include'
    Parameters:
      Location:
        'Fn::Sub': >-
          s3://${S3Bucket}/included_templates/settings_service_resources_template.yaml
```

You can also check the syntax in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html).

Comment: If I have several nested templates and I want to put them all in the main template. Then how is it in this case? I have already tried the option that you indicated earlier and it only works if we have only one nested template in the main template. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: CloudFormation supports only one AWS::Include on the same template level. To include multiple resource templates, you could move the Logical IDs to the main template and remove them from the nested ones (as shown [here](https://medium.com/@antonf_70246/aws-cloudformation-transforms-and-multiple-mappings-6475b332da3c)). Another possibility is to use [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) as suggested by @jarmod.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and simplest solution to the 51,200 bytes local CloudFormation template size limit is to upload the template to S3 and create/update your stack from that. That will allow you to indicate an S3 URL instead of sending the actual template body (limited to 51,200 bytes), and the template in S3 can be up to 1MB in size.

You also have the option to split your template into multiple, nested templates though that is typically more work as you have to arrange inputs and outputs accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The first option is really the fastest to implement. I'm trying to make the last point that you described and get to the truth. Where do you think my error is in the nested template? It seems to me in an attempt to use the parameter values that were declared in the main template. But I'm not sure.